# C++ Problem declaring multiple object instances on the same line

Tags: c++, object, initialization, declaration

For a homework assignment, I'm having a hard time understanding the behavior when the main class is instantiating two objects of the same class on the same line as follows. Note that the object of the assignment is for the class to behave like an int:

```
main () {
  MyClass x,y = 5;
  cout << "x = " << x << endl; // outputs x = 0...why not 5???
  cout << "y = " << y << endl; // outputs y = 5
}
```

and here's header file class definition:

```
class MyClass {
   public:
      MyClass(int initValue = 0); //constructor
      operator int() {return myValue}; //conversion operator to int
   private:
      int myValue;
}
```

and finally, my source file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(int initValue) {
   myValue = initValue;
}
```

Why doesn't x get initialized with the value of 5 like y does?

Comment: Just thinking about this...do I need to also overload the ',' operator?

Comment: @ChrisM- No, you do not need to overload comma.  Overloading comma would have meaning only when using the comma operator in an expression, not during a declaration.  It's very rare to need to overload comma, and I'd advise not doing so unless you're really sure you know what you're doing.  I've seen exactly one good use case for overloaded comma.

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking this. It seems that `int a,b=5;` would behave in exactly the same way (i.e. as `int a;` and `int b=5;`). So maybe this is expected behavior?

Comment: I never declare two object on the same line, just because of this. The classic problem is with a declaration like `int* x, y;`, where x is pointer and y is not! Horrible!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that C++ is parsing

```
MyClass x,y = 5;
```

As if you had written

```
MyClass x;
MyClass y = 5;
```

And so `x` is getting default-initialized rather than initialized with 5.  To fix this, change the line to read

```
MyClass x = 5, y = 5;
```

Comment: The driver file was supplied by the instructor so it'll get used as-is. It wasn't hard to figure out that your suggestion would indeed result in "x=5". I think the prof is challenging us to figure out how, if int a,b=5 would assign 5 to both a and b, then how to accomplish the same with our custom class.

Comment: @ChrisM: If your instructor thinks that "int x,y = 5;" will initialize both x and y to 5, then you need to exit that class as soon as possible and find a new instructor. That line will produce an uninitialized x and a y that equals 5.

Comment: Ha ha Daniel...thanks. He didn't imply that. I just assumed it (wrongly). I think by him including `MyClass x,y=5;` in the driver file driver, he's maybe just checking that our constructors properly initialize objects with and without assignment. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: A great reason why you shouldn't try and initialize all of your variables on the same line. There's absolutely no benefit to doing so: compressing all the initializations onto one line won't make your code run any faster, it just makes things harder to read for the next programmer (or in this case, the *current* programmer). Strive to write code that's crystal clear and intuitive to follow. Trust that the compiler will handle any necessary optimizations.